wms layer for mapbox gl js randomly stopped working how can i fix this?
I have had to do a proxy.js to load it in as it wasn't working without due to CORS
const express = require('express');
const request = require('request');
const app = express();

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});

app.get('/wms', (req, res) => {
  const bbox = req.query.bbox; // Fetch bbox from the query params
  const wmsUrl = `https://spatial-gis.information.qld.gov.au/arcgis/services/GeoscientificInformation/GeologyDetailed/MapServer/WMSServer?bbox=${bbox}&format=image/png&service=WMS&version=1.3.0&request=GetMap&CRS=EPSG:3857&transparent=true&width=256&height=256&layers=0`;
  request(wmsUrl).pipe(res); // Proxy the WMS response back to the client
});

app.listen(3001, () => {
  console.log('Proxy server running on port 3001');
});


i also had to import proj4 to handle the cords system
here is part of my wms code for mapbox gl js
      // Function to fetch WMS URL manually for the whole bounding box
      const fetchWMSForBounds = (bbox) => {
        const [sw3857, ne3857] = [toEPSG3857([bbox[0], bbox[1]]), toEPSG3857([bbox[2], bbox[3]])];
        const wmsUrl = `http://localhost:3001/wms?bbox=${sw3857[0]},${sw3857[1]},${ne3857[0]},${ne3857[1]}`;

        // Remove the existing WMS layer and source if present
        if (map.current?.getSource('wms-source')) {
          map.current?.removeLayer('wms-layer');
          map.current?.removeSource('wms-source');
        }
        // Add a single raster layer for the entire bounding box
        map.current?.addSource('wms-source', {
          type: 'image',
          url: wmsUrl, // Single image for the whole bounding box
          coordinates: [
            [bbox[0], bbox[3]], // top-left
            [bbox[2], bbox[3]], // top-right
            [bbox[2], bbox[1]], // bottom-right
            [bbox[0], bbox[1]], // bottom-left
          ],
        });

        map.current?.addLayer({
          id: 'wms-layer',
          type: 'raster',
          source: 'wms-source',
          paint: {},
        });
      };

      // Handle map movement to request the bounding box of the visible area
      map.current?.on('moveend', () => {
        const bounds = map.current?.getBounds();
        if (bounds) {
          const bbox = [
            bounds.getWest(),
            bounds.getSouth(),
            bounds.getEast(),
            bounds.getNorth(),
          ];
          fetchWMSForBounds(bbox);
        }
      });

this is the error i am getting
app-index.js:33 Error: Could not load image because of The source image could not be decoded.. Please make sure to use a supported image type such as PNG or JPEG. Note that SVGs are not supported.
at eval (mapbox-gl.js:31:75966)
The wms worked fine before and was loading great. Not sure why it stopped
